# flutter repository branching convention

Tags: flutter, github, branching-strategy

In [flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) repository. there are some branches containing `candidate` for example: `flutter-2.7-candidate.1`. could someone please explain what are these branches for? and what is the logic behind naming them?

Answer (score 0):

The branches like "flutter-2.7-candindate.1" in the Flutter repository are used for managing the release process of Flutter. Let's break down the naming convention and understanding their purpose:

1. "flutter-2..7": This part of the branch name indicates the major version of Flutter. In this case, it's version 2.7.
2. "candidate": This part signifies that this branch contains a potential candidate for a beta release. It's a stage where the code is considered stable enough for testing by a wider audience but not yet ready for a full stable release.
3. "1.": This part indicates the specific candidate withing the 2.7 version. It's common to have multiple candidate branches within a major version, especially if there are bug fixes or minor updates being tested before the actual beta release.

The logic behind naming these branches is to provide a clear indication of the stage of development and the version being worked on. The "flutter-2.7-candindate.1" branch, for instance, indicates that it's part of the development process for version 2.7 of Flutter, and it's the first candidate for beta release within that version. As development progresses, more candidates may be created and tested before a beta release is finalized.

Your may find additional information in the [Flutter Release process](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Release-process)